# how to use "buildhistory" in yocto build system?

Tags: yocto

I wanted to keep track of the "builds" that gets created using the yocto-build-system. And after doing some search, came to know about "buildhistory" feature provided by yocto-project.

They say, for enabling the "buildhistory", we need to do following:

Edit .../build/conf/local.conf
and add:

```
INHERIT += "buildhistory"
BUILDHISTORY_COMMIT = "1"
```

and then rerun the "bitbake" for initializing the buildhistory directory.

I did the same, but I am unable to locate the buildhistory directory as such.

Can anybody let me know, how to use this "buildhistory", and how to see the build-differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It'll create the buildhistory directory in ${TOPDIR}, which points to your build directory. The build directory is normally build, unless you've specified something else.

You can go into the buildhistory directory yourself, and use git (gitk, tig), though it's usually a lot more convenient to stay in ${TOPDIR} and run e.g.

```
buildhistory-diff
```

Have you checked the documentation: http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#maintaining-build-output-quality?

When you enable buildhistory, you'll get a couple of directories "images" and "packages" along with a file metadata-revs in your buildhistory directory. (And there should also be .git directory). In these directories, buildhistory will keep all changes by committing them to it's repository after each bitbake command. Amongst other things, package version & revisions, packages installed in images, sizes, etc are all kept track of. This is all outlined in the doc link.

Try adding IMAGE_INSTALL_append="some-package" to your local.conf, and run `buildhistory-diff` after bitbakeing your image. This should tell you that a package was added to the image.

You could also go into the buildhistory directory and run `git log`, `gitk`, or `tig`there to check out whats commited.

If you're still not getting any output, paste the tree structure of the buildhistory directory to pastebin.

Comment: I did check, the documentation link shared. I have got the "buildhistory" folder inside the "build" folder. But now, I do not get any "difference" when i do "buildhistory-diff" in the ${TOPDIR} (i.e. the "build" directory). I tried changing "revision" of one of the component in two successive builds. Need to know, what kind of changes are being tracked with the buildhistory? also, does it keep changes, of only successive builds, or keep local repo of all the builds. how does it do that? kindly provide insight.

Comment: I did proceed, as per your directions. And now I have got it working for me. To summarize: 1) inside, "buildhistory" folder, "git log" was able to get me the logs pertaining to each commits made, for successful builds. 2) After that, I added "Image_INSTALL_append=..." in my local.conf file, and did attempt to build image again. Post this, when I did "buildhistory-diff -p ." inside the "buildhistory" folder, I could see the difference in the image, from the last one. Thanks.