# Cant get Java to run on Ostro

Tags: java, yocto

I have built a Ostro image from the current repo and built this on a 14.04 Ubuntu machine. I have successfully installed this on a target machine with intel i7-64 bit architecture. As per my opinion Java should have come packaged with this however when I type java -version on the command line (Inside the target) I get Java command not found. How to overcome this and what do I miss. Please consider me a novice in this scenario (Flashing an OS for the first time) I am also not sure how to add the Help wanted tag with this question as this is not an issue exactly and am pretty sure I am missing something. Would just need a guide here to get me started.

Also here is my bblayers.conf

```
# The following layers are available in the combined repository.
# Their recipes are filtered via white-listing in ostro.conf,
# i.e. even if the layer gets added, only explicitly listed recipes
# are enabled. Enable layers here only if they have enabled recipes
# to avoid warnings about empty layers.

# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-efl"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-filesystems"
OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-gnome"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-gpe"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-initramfs"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia"
OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-networking"
OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-oe"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-perl"
OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-python"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-ruby"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-systemd"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/meta-xfce"
# OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-openembedded/toolchain-layer"
OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-java"
OSTRO_LAYERS += "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-soletta"

BBLAYERS ?= "${OSTRO_LAYERS}"

# toaster uses this hint to decide whether it let's the user
# remove a layer from BBLAYERS. All layers which provide something
# that is required to build ostro-image should be listed here.
# We do not really track that, so add all layers also here.
BBLAYERS_NON_REMOVABLE ?= "${OSTRO_LAYERS}"
```

After adding the suggested part in the answer below I get:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'classpath-tools' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'classpath-tools' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['classpath-tools']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'cacao' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: cacao was skipped: missing required distro feature 'x11' (not in DISTRO_FEATURES)
NOTE: Runtime target 'cacao' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['cacao']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'classpath' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: classpath was skipped: missing required distro feature 'x11' (not in DISTRO_FEATURES)
NOTE: Runtime target 'classpath' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['classpath']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'jamvm' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
ERROR: jamvm was skipped: missing required distro feature 'x11' (not in DISTRO_FEATURES)
NOTE: Runtime target 'jamvm' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['jamvm']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'classpath-examples' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'classpath-examples' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['classpath-examples']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'openjdk-8-vm-jamvm' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'openjdk-8-vm-jamvm' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['openjdk-8-vm-jamvm']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'openjdk-8-vm-cacao' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'openjdk-8-vm-cacao' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['openjdk-8-vm-cacao']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'shadowopenjdk-8-jre' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'shadowopenjdk-8-jre' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['shadowopenjdk-8-jre']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'ostro-image-noswupd'
ERROR: No eligible RPROVIDERs exist for 'ostro-image-noswupd'
NOTE: Runtime target 'ostro-image-noswupd' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['ostro-image-noswupd']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES '\' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target '\' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['\\']
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'classpath-common' (but /home/ubuntu/Desktop/ostro-os/meta-ostro/recipes-image/images/ostro-image-noswupd.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'classpath-common' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['classpath-common']
```

Comment: I guess classpath recipe must be there in meta-java layer. check using find meta-java | grep -i "classpath". There must be a classpath_*.bb

Answer (score 2):

It seems java is not being installed in your rootfs. You must include following lines in build/conf/local.conf to enable it.

```
# Possible provider: cacao-initial-native and jamvm-initial-native 
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-initial-native = "cacao-initial-native"

# Possible provider: cacao-native and jamvm-native
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/java-native = "jamvm-native"

# Optional since there is only one provider for now  
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/javac-native = "ecj-bootstrap-native"
```

You also need to add some of these images in build/conf/local.conf as per your requirement. These are optional. you can modify it as per your requirement.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " openjdk-7-jre \
openjdk-7-vm-jamvm \
openjdk-7-vm-cacao \
classpath \
classpath-common \
classpath-examples \
classpath-tools \
jamvm \
cacao \
"
```

Comment: Where does the second part go? I have the first one in my local.conf under build/conf folder

Comment: Ive tried this for two days, is there a way where in I can install Java additionally? on top after OS deployment?

Comment: The second part will also go in build/conf/local.conf

Comment: How to know before hand which packages will go into the build? Any command to verify that?

Comment: If you manage to get a good package manager into rootfs like apt-get then alternatively you can install java after OS deployment just like in case of ubuntu

Comment: To check list of packages available please check my previous answer to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878640/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-exact-list-of-packages-that-will-be-installed-in-the/46882827#46882827