# List packages which will be included in host Yocto SDK

Tags: yocto

I'm currently encountering an issue whereby the version of OpenCV being included in the target image is different to that which is being included in the host SDK (3.4.x as opposed to 3.3.x).

In order to better debug this, I want to list the packages (and their versions) which will be included in the host SDK produced by `bitbake core-image-weston -c populate_sdk`.

How can I do this? Note: I'm using the command line and am not using Toaster.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe something like `bitbake -e core-image-weston | grep PACKAGES | grep -i sdk` ? (not sure)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878640/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-exact-list-of-packages-that-will-be-installed-in-the

Comment: Hi @Benjamin Crawford if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 4):

One good way to debug such package or sdk issues is yocto  [buildhistory](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.8/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#maintaining-build-output-quality)

Add the content below to your local.conf

```
 INHERIT += "buildhistory"
 BUILDHISTORY_COMMIT = "1"
 BUILDHISTORY_FEATURES = "image package sdk" # maybe already default value
```

A new folder will be created under build/buildhistory/ , which allows you to verify packages, sdk and the image in a easy manner.

Edit:
Since you want it before compiling everything:

```
bitbake -g core-image-weston -c populate_sdk && cat pn-buildlist | sort | uniq | bitbake -s > dependencies
```

Comment: good way indeed but it works after building it, not before :/

Comment: @Nayfe Agreed, I can't consider this answer as I need to know which packages will be included before committing to a build.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut I added an solution that works before building it.