# Understand yocto bitbake-layers show-recipes

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am newber for Ycoto.
Want to know the output of **bitbake-layers show-recipes** was list all packages build to target images?
For example: below shown python-pygobject, that is means **python-pygobject** will be build/compile to target images?

```
python-pygobject:
  meta-python2         3.34.0
python-pygpgme:
  meta-python2         0.3
python-pyhamcrest:
  meta-python2         1.9.0
python-pyiface:
  meta-python2         0.0.11
python-pyinotify:
  meta-python2         0.9.6
python-pyjks:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bitbake-layers show-layers
```

Will show all layers you have added e.g. you may add `meta`, `meta-ti`, `meta-python` etc.

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes
```

Will then show all recipes that the above layers you have added provide. Note that when you build an image, you won't necessarily build all available recipes. An image such as `core-image-weston` will have a list of recipes it will build by default, and you can add in optional recipes such as `vim` by appending it to your `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable e.g. in local.conf:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " vim"
```

To see which recipes are included in a built image, you can see the manifest file in `./build/tmp/deploy/images/<your_image>/<image_name>.manifest` or use bitbake to output the recipes [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878640/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-exact-list-of-packages-that-will-be-installed-in-the).

Comment: @ORR, Thanks, one more question. when run bitbake **core-image-weston**, How it collects recipes to determine what recipes will be built and what recipes will not built?, Is any documentaion?

Comment: @RobberPen You can find images defined in a similar manner to recipes. So `core-image-weston` would be in meta/recipes-graphics/images/core-image-weston.bb` and in there will be variables such as `IMAGE_FEATURES` that define what is installed and may inherit the `core-image.bbclass` meta file found in `meta/classes/core-image.bbclass`. For an overview of the different images you can [look here](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/images.html)  or for a more in-depth look, you can find the relevant bb file and look through it.

Comment: To clarify, if you look in `core-image.bbclass` you might find image features such as weston defined to include `packagegroup-core-weston`, and again this relates to a file which you can find in  `recipes-graphics/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-weston.bb` and it will list `weston weston-init weston-examples wayland-utils`